# selectively hide client side validation error messages coming from Data Annotations attributes

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I want to get validation error message from Required attribute when no input provided,  but i don' t want to get validation error message from StringLength attribute and still make it work as a input controller. Is it possbile to do that?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FirstName)

[Required]
[StringLength(80, MinimumLength =2)]
public string FirstName {get;set;}
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you are asking, can you try and explain a bit more

Comment: Kindly give some example.

Comment: do you never want to see the error message for `StringLength`?  30 seems short for email maxlength btw..

Comment: @Gagan Jaura @ musefan actually it is just an example not from a real project. What i wanted to learn was to prevent getting validation error from stringlength attribute. i think Chris Pratt gave the answer though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unobtrusive client-side validation in MVC is just jQuery Validation. As you can see from the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/), if you don't want something validated, you just need to remove the rule(s):

```
$('Email').rules('remove', 'minlength maxlength');
```